# Nonexistent file path in Task Manager

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

While browsing through the start-up tab in Task Manager I came across an entry called "Program" with no icon, supposedly located at **"C:\Program" Files (x86\FKL\emsvc.exe**.

Searching for the executable using File Explorer returns no results. What is going on here?

[image]

Comment: That is a keylogger according to 
iwantsoft.com/faqs/
and
kmint21.com/familykeylogger/

It may be wise to download and run the free version of MalwareBytes from malwarebytes.com

Comment: You should see the path the program is mentioning. It says "C:\Program" Files (x86\FKL\emsvc.exe, which is an illegal dir because of the position of **"** (apostrophe). As @Gantendo says, it must be a malware

Comment: The path is `c:\program.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bogus entry - the file reference is invalid.
The reference of `"C:\Program" Files (x86)\FKL\emsvc.exe` is invalid.
You can find better information about the file by using
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Try to see if this folder exists: `C:\Program Files (x86)\FKL`
or perhaps `C:\Program Files\FKL`.

The software in question is perhaps the free
[FKL KeyLogger](https://www.kmint21.com/familykeylogger/),
described as an invisible keystroke logger, aimed at
"know what others are doing on your own pc when you leave".

If you or someone around you have installed this software,
then uninstall it.
If you have found the above FKL folder, ensure afterward that the
folder was deleted.

The latest [FAQ](https://www.iwantsoft.com/faqs/)
describes this uninstall procedure
(which might not apply to your version):

> If you have agent and report viewer on your PC, then you should
> complete the following steps:
>
> - Click Ctrl+Alt+Shift+U  and enter your password to open the Report Viewer;
> - On the toolbar, click the "Uninstall" button.
>
> If you have only Report Viewer installed on your PC, then you should
> follow the standard procedure of uninstall:
>
> - Find "FKL" item in the Start Menu (or Uninstall list);
> - Choose "Uninstall FKL".

If you have no idea how this software got into your computer,
you might be infected. In that case, see the post
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: If OP doesn't know what that process is then I doubt they have the password to open the Report Viewer....